# Can CMake Generate Theos Makefiles?

Tags: ios, makefile, cmake, theos

I've created an iOS project using [Theos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos). Its [Makefile format](http://uv.howett.net/ipf.html) is very simple - basically just a list of source files and libraries/frameworks. All I would need CMake to do is update the source list and libraries in this file. Can CMake do this?

This is my current Makefile:

```
ARCHS=armv6
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/common.mk

APPLICATION_NAME = TestApp
TestApp_FILES = main.m gltest.cpp testAppDelegate.m ES1Renderer.m EAGLView.m
TestApp_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit CoreGraphics OpenGLES QuartzCore

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/application.mk
```

It seems to me that CMake can't generate anything that isn't a standard Unix Makefile, IDE project, etc. I have the feeling that I would need to write my own custom CMake toolchain file to do everything that Theos does for me.

It would be OK if CMake just dumped its source list into a text file, and then I would edit it from there using some other automation tool/script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get CMake to generate the Makefile using the **FILE(WRITE)** command:

```
file(WRITE ${MAKE_FILE}
     "ARCHS=" ${ARCHS} "\n"
     "APPLICATION_NAME = " ${PROJECT_NAME} "\n"
     ${PROJECT_NAME} "_FILES = " ${IOS_SOURCES} "\n"
     ${PROJECT_NAME} "_FRAMEWORKS = " ${FRAMEWORK_DEPS} "\n\n"
     "include ${THEOS_PATH}/makefiles/common.mk\n"
     "include ${THEOS_PATH}/makefiles/application.mk"
     )
```

I also made an empty toolchain so that CMake didn't spend time configuring compilers for my system.

```
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

# Just point to anything that exists. 
# We don't need CMake to generate proper build files.
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Skip the platform compiler checks
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
```